# rspec doesn't see fields dynamically added or removed by cocoon in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

In my application in Rails 4, I use Cocoon to have nested forms.

It works well in the browser, but I want to add some tests with rspec.

If I make a `click_link("add")` (or 'remove') in my test, rspec doesn't see any modification (I print `page.body` before and after).

I also tried with a `sleep(10)` but it's the same.

How could I test if the action (add or remove a nested form) works well ?

Thanks

EDIT:

The scenario to test :

```
scenario "nested form" do
  user_sign_in

  contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact)

  visit new_message_path
  expect(page).to have_text("New message")

  puts page.html

  click_link('Add an action')  # <------ click on the link to add a new nested form

  puts page.html     # <--- the page is the same as before the click

  expect(page).to have_text("New action")

  user_sign_out
end
```

Comment: Can you post your entire scenario? Do you have `js: true` passed as an option to the relevant test?

Comment: @ChrisPeters Thanks. You are right, I don't pass the ````js: true```` option. I didn't know this. I will look in this direction. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, you'll need the `selenium-webdriver` or `capybara-webkit` gem. My impression is that the former is easier to get up and running with.

Comment: @ChrisPeters : thanks for all ! If you write an answer whith the ````js: true```` I will accept it.

Comment: Added the answer. Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to test JavaScript-related functionality, then you need to pass `js: true` as an option to the related `scenario`s:

```
scenario "nested form", js: true do
  user_sign_in
  contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact)

  visit new_message_path
  expect(page).to have_text("New message")

  click_link('Add an action')
  expect(page).to have_text("New action")

  user_sign_out
end
```

In order to do this, you also need either the `selenium-webdriver` or `capybara-webkit` gems. My impression is that Selenium is easier to get started with, but the WebKit one runs much faster.

Note that you can also pass `js: true` to `feature`, `context`, or `describe` if you need to test several `scenario`s with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Chris, it was exactly that. ````js: true```` was missing. Thanks also for all advices, it's very detailed.