# Capybara form value set with cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

I am trying to write a test for a form with nested attributes using Cocoon and rails 4.  The problem is that I cannot find the form element to set.

I have tried the following commented out variations but get element not found:

```
click_link('Add Owner') # should display the fields

#fill_in 'First Name', with: "sean"
#find("input#horse_owner_attributes_fname").set('sean')
#find(:xpath, '//input[@id="horse_owner_attributes_lname"]').set("sean")
```

I am not sure if my problem is the dynamic nature of the cocoon 'link_to_add_association' or just that I do not know how to use find, or some other reason.

My main form is:

```
#owner
  #owner_from_list
    = f.collection_select(:owner_id, @owners, :id,  :fname, { :prompt => "Existing Owner" }, {:class => 'form-control'} ) # shows drop down of existing records

= link_to_add_association 'Add Owner', f, :owner, :class => "btn btn-default btn-sm", :data => {"association-insertion-method" => "after" } # to add a new record
```

and my add owner partial:

```
= f.inputs do
  .nested-fields
    = f.input :fname, :as => :string, label: "First Name", hint: "Owner's first name REQUIRED", :required => true  
    = f.input :lname, :as => :string, label: "Last Name", hint: "Last name REQUIRED", :required => true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem I had.

If you want to fill in fields dynamically added after you click on the Cocoon link, you should pass `js: true` as an option to the related scenario.

You can see my question and the excellent answer Chris Peters give to me :
[rspec doesn't see fields dynamically added or removed by cocoon in nested form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438656/rspec-doesnt-see-fields-dynamically-added-or-removed-by-cocoon-in-nested-form) to have more informations.